# Laravel Pivot table get value and pass to blade template

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, many-to-many, laravel-blade

i'm trying to get all the **Level_id** and **Term_id** on my **intermediate table** using **many to many relationship** but i couldn't make it work and i want to pass it to my view  using **ordered list html.**

i always end up with this..**Trying to get property of non-object**

**Controller:**

```
   public function get_term_level()
 {

    $terms=Term::find(1);

    foreach ($terms->level as $tm) {
        $tm->pivot->Level_id;
    }




    return view('term_level.index',compact('terms'));

 }
```

**Term Model** same as with my **LevelModel**

```
public function level(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Level::class, 'term_levels')->withPivot('Term_id', 'Level_id');
  }
```

**View**

```
 @foreach ($terms->pivot as $tm  )
     <ul>
     <li>{{ $tm->Term_id }}</li>
         {{ $tm->Level_id }}
     </ul>@endforeach
```

Comment: is `'Term_id', 'Level_id'` are pivot fields ? i think these are relation filed for term and level. can you show  us your pivot table `term_levels` ?

Comment: yes Term_id and Level_id  are both pivot fields which parent is terms and levels table and inside my pivot table which is term_level only the primary key and foriegn key inside nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Try this (inside your controller):

```
foreach ($terms->level()->get() as $tm) {
    $tm->pivot->Level_id;
}
```